# 2005 Honda Pilot, no parking lights, or dash board lights. all others do work.

Tags: honda, lights, pilot

repair: no parking or dash board lights.
all relays and fuses seem to be OK, and i switched two , results are the same. 
any ideas ??

Comment: Welcome to the site. Asking "*any ideas*" does not lead to good answers and may invoke debate. It is better to ask a specific question. Please use the [edit] feature to do so. We will do our best to help from there.

Answer (score 1):

When you test fuses visual confirmation isn't enough and is time consuming when there are multiple fuses to check. Use a multimeter, there are exposed parts on most fuses. Create an extension wire that will run from your battery negative terminal to the multimeter and test for voltage key on engine off or running.

Check fuse 10 (US models) in the passenger side kick panel fusebox. It feeds power for both the tail lights and dash lights. If it is blown, suspect a short to ground at the trailer connector if equipped.

[image]
[image]